# Why isn't Stack Overflow adopting HTML5 features for form input?

Tags: discussion, design

I am building a website and am trying to learn the best practices from Stack Overflow at the same time. This would sometimes involve inspecting the underlying code. I notice that Stack Overflow does not use the new [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) form inputs for email and [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). Are there any good reasons that it is not adopting these new features?

Comment: A better question is what are the reasons **for*** adopting them. (You're probably right but I can never get behind "new is always better")

Comment: @RichardTingle, I am trying to learn here. I think you are also right that new is not always better.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms

Comment: @Oded, uuuuuhhhh, even if not supported, wouldn't it revert to text?

Comment: First, we do use some HTML 5 features - the `placeholder` attribute, for instance. For others - where would you use email and url outside of the (not very often used) user profile page?

Comment: @Oded, Login and registering dummy accounts?

Comment: Required reading, regarding why something was not implemented: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx

Comment: What do you mean with "registering dummy accounts"?

Comment: @Arjan he probably thinks there's no validation whatsoever so anyone can enter any email and register account with it. (of course this is wrong and there is server side validation, plus to register you have to use OpenID :))

Answer (score 7):

I am not an authority on such matters, but I can take a good guess.

> If if ain't broke, don't fix it.

The current method works well enough, and there are probably far more important to things to be working on (like HATS); such a change will typically come when it is needed, and no earlier.

Comment: Ah... hats. Well.. Ok, that counts as one good reason :)